# cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com' on GAE + Pubsub

Tags: google-api-php-client

Good day fellow coders,

I'm having trouble using PubSub with google-api-php-client on Google App Engine.

Everything used to work perfectly but since this morning I'm having curl errors on the www.googleapis.com host.

Would you have any idea how to solve this ?

Thank you very much for your time !

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException

Message: cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'www.googleapis.com' (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Filename: /base/data/home/apps/{my_app}/2.396148512822725307/application/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php
```

Comment: Hello again, as for today this changed a little bit, some of the times I have this error (1/10 of the times). The other times it works normally. Is it possible that this error has nothing to do with my code but with some GAE dns errors ?

Comment: Started to have the same issue today.  Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove extension=curl.so  from your php.ini

it is not a nice looking fix, but it will get the pub/sub working again.

Comment: This is exactly what did, then we had to rewrite some of our code (we were using curl a lot in our project). We replace it with other methods and now we're OK. 

Thank you !